# What power sources exist in D&D and what influence do they have on their heroes?

Tags: dnd-4e

D&D seems to have *many* different power sources. Is there a complete list somewhere? What flavour is attached to them?

Also, how do the classes relate to the power sources?

Are power sources important to the mechanics?

Comment: Hey John.  Sorry, but this is not a very focused question, somewhat amounting to "please sum up a big part of the 4e rulebook to me," and probably not a good fit for RPG.SE. Please see our FAQ and its links to "How to ask a good question."

Comment: @mxyzplk It doesn't involve summing up any large part of the 4e rulebook at all. This question should not be closed.

Comment: Are we talking about the nature of power sources here?

Comment: Sorry for the Un-focused question, I'm asking about the different types of heroes.

Comment: @BrianBallsun-Stanton Yeah, looks like we are, but the asker didn't know the term so I didn't want to add it in; that term would be a part of the answer.

Comment: @Brian I think that's the correct translation, yes.

Comment: Okay, did a fairly large edit. Does this fit your intent, @john?

Answer (score 12):

The class you choose dictates your power source. Most classes draw from just one power source, though some will occasionally dip into other sources.

The power source is a narrative device to provide you information as to *where* your character got their abilities and training. A martial character has been schooled in how to fight; an arcane character can draw on magic; a divine character receives their powers from their deity. However, it does occasionally have mechanical implications as well. Numerous powers and feats reference things like "arcane powers" or "divine powers" or even "martial classes." These provide restrictions, benefits and balance to the game.

The 4e power sources:

- **Martial** - represents military training or general prowess with physical weaponry. (fighter, rogue, warlord, ranger, executioner assassin)
- **Divine** - represents that powers come due to a connection with a deity or the spiritual realm (cleric, paladin, runepriest, invoker, avenger)
- **Arcane** - your powers come from magical sources (wizard, warlock, swordmage, bard, artificer, sorcerer)
- **Psionic** - your powers are mental. (psion, ardent, battlemind, monk)
- **Primal** - your powers come from a deep connection to the world and the spirits (warden, shaman, druid, barbarian, seeker)
- **Shadow** - your powers come form opening a well of energy from the Shadowfell (assassin, vampire).

Power sources are occasionally important to mechanics, but mostly they are dictated by class. You can have access to more than one power source by multiclassing or by using a hybrid class, but mostly you just have one power source. The mechanical impact is mostly in the choice of feats and paragon paths (some are limited to just martial characters, etc.), but for the most part, you won't see the impact of the power source directly on your gameplay. It's up to you to integrate its flavor into how you play your character.